# Term to describe the phenomenon of people starting conversations when you're about to leave

Tags: vocabulary

As suggested by the title, I am looking for a term to describe the well-known (?) phenomenon, that some people often start quite lengthy conversations with someone standing in a doorway about to leave. I am sure I came across such a term some time ago, but cannot find it now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Thanks a lot! That's actually where I read about it in the first place, but I had forgot about it :)

Comment: Could it be a go-ssip, or an exitchange or redepartee ;-)

Comment: @long: I feel like there is a pun I am supposed to get, but I don't...

Comment: go-ssip, playing off of "go" and "gossip".  exitchange, a play off of "exit" and "exchange" (as in to talk).  Redepartee, as in continuously attempting to depart (the person departing is a departee; re is a predicate indicating a repetition).

Comment: Thanks, Doc, and sorry, long, for failing to appreciate the intended amusement. I'm a bit embarrassed I didn't quite get it, but I'm a bit tired.

Answer (score 3):

In medical circles it is often referred to as the ***doorknob syndrome***. Typically when the doctor is leaving the examining room and has his hand on the doorknob, the patient goes: *by the way doctor* or *can I ask one more thing ...*

Comment: Thanks for your input! That's very interesting and I hadn't heard it before. I can certainly see how it could be very frustrating for doctors. I upvoted your answer but didn't "accept" it, as I am hoping to find a more general term.

Comment: I'm sure there is no harm in applying this concept more generally - there is nothing specifically *medical* about it. But I agree ... maybe there is another expression.

Comment: Yes, but to me, "syndrome" indicates some sort of medical problem.

Comment: Perhaps - is there anything medical about the *Washington monument syndrome*?

Comment: I hadn't heard about the "Washington monument syndrome" before; I guess it should be pointed out that English isn't my mother tongue. It is probably true that syndrome could have a meaning outside of the medical context, as suggested for example by Merriam-Webster online dictionary: "... 2. a set of concurrent things (as emotions or actions) that usually form an identifiable pattern".

Comment: I can't really think of a more picturesque expression - but perhaps there is ....

Comment: Well, Mari-Lou directed to me to a thread on the same subject in her comment above. As far as I can see, your particular suggestion isn't in this thread (although there are other suggestions involving doorknob), so I appreciate your input.

Comment: Just checked the answers there. They are quite different and I personally wouldn't recommend any of those. As the answerer suggests **doorknobbing** has been taken over by perverts. The other suggestions have no merit.

Comment: Well, maybe you're right. I definitely agree though, that "doorknob" seems to have been given quite a different meaning, thus rendering it completely useless for the (here) intended purpose.

Comment: Not necessarily - I would avoid using it as a verb that's all. If you use it as a 'syndrome' or 'phenomenon' I'm sure you will be safe and fully understood.

Comment: Well, I think it's safe to say that the people who are likely to use the word for its vulgar meaning, may not necessarily appreciate such a distinction in a conversation.

Comment: @user49727: I wonder if you could post this answer to my original question. I know it's ancient and I think I even accepted an answer, but I think your version (with "syndrome" to remove any, um, sexual implication) is better.